# Is it correct and natural to say "your account is pulling up" meaning the computer is processing info to show it on the screen?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, collocations

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *your account is pulling up* meaning the computer is processing info to show it on the screen? For example:

> Sir, would you please hang on a bit. **Your account is pulling up**. The computer is a bit slow today so it'll take a while before I can tell what you were charged for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call this as not sounding like natural English.

"I'm pulling up your account details but the system is a bit slow today." Would be a more natural usage if you want to use "pulling".

The phrasing that you are using is more likely to be used to indicate the arrival of something - "The train is pulling up at the station." "I'm just pulling up outside" etc.

Consider "Your account is loading" or "Your account is being retrieved" as clearer alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct! This is because the action of "pulling up" is something that someone/something does to an account.

The action "to pull up," in this context, has a subject and an object. "I'm pulling up your account." Or maybe, "The computer is pulling up your account."
If you want to use passive voice, you could say, "Your account is being pulled up" or "getting pulled up."

Answer (score 0):

No, "**your account is pulling up**" doesn't sound natural because "pulling" is the action the *operator* is performing, not the account.

What action is the account performing? The account is *being pulled up* (passive voice) or, more naturally, *the account is **coming up***.

Think of a long rope attached to a bucket deep in a well: the person is *pulling up* the bucket of water, the bucket of water is *coming up* the well.